# Where to put simple functions in an Ember project

Tags: ember.js

So... while I'm learning all of this Ember CLI world - things are going well. However, I can't seem to understand where all the normal ol javascript/jQuery  utility stuff I use on a normal project goes... for example --- [this sticky footer thing](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/ziGbE)... where do I put this? It's blowing my mind...

```
// dynamic weighted footer
var watchFooter = function() {

  // define the height variable
  var footerHeight;

    // get the height of the footer and store it in 'footerHeight'
    footerHeight = $('.container.footer').outerHeight();

  // Share that info with the dependent elements
  $('.footer-buffer').css('height', footerHeight);
  $('.container.master').css('margin-bottom', -(footerHeight));

};

// run on window resize - and on load
$(window).resize(watchFooter).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: This is not Ember, it is "jQuember". Rewrite this as a component.

Answer (score 4):

`ember-cli` has a blueprint for creating utilities.  You can generate one using this command:

```
ember g util my-util
```

It will create the file `app/util/my-util.js`:

```
export default function myUtil() {
  console.log('TESTING!');  // I've added this to confirm it is working
  return true;
}
```

Then, in order to use your new utility you can `import` it when it is needed like so:

```
import MyUtil from '../utils/my-util';
```

And then use it like this:

```
MyUtil();  // this will print TESTING! to the console
```

---

You could also create a `view` and use the `didInsertElement` event hook.  You can read more about it here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_didInsertElement

You would generate a view using this command:

```
ember g view my-view
```

Edit the resulting file `app/views/my-view.js` to use the `didInsertElement` event hook:

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: So sometimes I would be using little component in certain places / but what about in this example, where it's a site-wide layout function? Would you import into app.js? and invoke the function there too? Thanks for getting me in the right direction. This scenario doesn't seem like a global thing and not a 'view' - and I guess semantically - it could be a component?

Comment: Forgive me, I thought you were asking specifically about utils consumed in specific parts of your application.  So, you're just looking to establish a footer for the layout?  I agree that refactoring into a component would be a good solution.

Comment: A component is more like `{{put thing here}}` where - the footer thing involves html with quite a stretch --- and is always everywhere... so --- it's not something you can really place. So far --- util sounds pretty right on - doing a lot of research... I mean - really I think it should just be at the top of the app - just a global script --- run's once... well... and overtime the window resizes.... still think component?

Comment: If you were to create a footer component named `my-footer`, you could use the block helper to yield the footer's content.  `{{#my-footer}} footer content {{/my-footer}}`.  Check out the guides on components and play around with the different patterns that've been discussed.  Hope this helps!  http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/components/

Comment: To clarify, the footer component would work well if you need to use it in multiple templates.  You could also just set up a nested route that yields your page's content and the footer remains static throughout the application.  Not knowing enough about your application and how you've structured it makes it difficult for me to prescribe an exact solution.

Comment: Well the structure of this specific thing involves divs that are in the header, and footer... I just want to put some scripts somewhere that are application wide. So, I'm excited about where I could use components, but this doesn't seem like the place to use them. 'email-signup-form' sounds like a good component. A site wide layout script that watches the content of the footer's height and makes decisions that effect many other divs in different parts of the application, sounds more like a utility. With that in mind - what do you suggest?